# How to view the common Values between multiple keys in Same HashMap in java?

Tags: java, oop

```
HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<String>> = new HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<String>>(); 
ArrayList<constructor> frndList = new ArrayList<constructor> ();
```

In single hash map i will use the integer value as key and for that key i will be adding multiple values using list
now my question is key 1 having two values that same value is available in key 3 then i have to view that?

Comment: you have both the values in `key 3` or only one of them?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? A solution would be to iterate over the [entrySet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29) and check whether the [value](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#getValue%28%29) [contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) the searched string.

Comment: Do you need an efficient algorithm or just an algorithm? The data structure you are using is not very efficient for this scenario. But if your data is small, this structure will be OK.

Comment: Please update your post. It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: i am using small program so it okay . I want to make my question clear   key1 {a,b,c} key 2 {g,h,b} key3{z,g,a}    now key1 and key 2 having b value common so i have to view b similarly key 2 and key 3 having common value as g so i have to display g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.out.println("Enter first key");
    int f=scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter second key");
    int s=scan.nextInt();
    ArrayList<String> t1=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> t2=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> mf=new ArrayList<String>();
    t1.addAll(map.get(f));
    t2.addAll(map.get(s));
    for(String temp1:t1)
    {
        if(t2.contains(temp1))
        {
            mf.add(temp1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to manually loop inside your HashMap

```
dupl = null;
for(ek:map.keys()){
    if(ek.get(ek).contains(my_value)){
        dupl = ek.get(ek)
        break;
    }
}
```

if dupl is not null, you have a value in key ek